# How to wasm Debugging?

Tags: javascript, debugging, webassembly

I'm currently conducting research related to WebAssembly. I've only started two days ago, so I have many things to learn, and time is limited. I'm targeting the WebAssembly compiler Emscripten and trying to run it using various runtime tools. For example, running an index.html file (containing JavaScript and WebAssembly) in a web browser using 'emrun,' executing .js files in a command-line environment with Node.js, and, finally, creating WebAssembly as an independent module and running it with WebAssembly runtime tools. My questions are as follows:

1. I want to execute WebAssembly-generated .html files in a web browser and then parse the JavaScript console output. This is necessary for comparing the results.
2. I want to debug in a WebAssembly runtime environment. In other words, I'd like to debug using a tool like 'pwndbg' in a command-line environment. If this isn't feasible, I'd at least like to make it work in a command-line environment (I've already tried various methods).

Thank you for addressing my questions.

I've already tried many debugging tools, but they don't work. Maybe it really doesn't work, or I did something wrong.

Comment: _"parse the JavaScript console output."_ - Please elaborate. Do you mean you want a script running in the same page to be able to read-back what was previously written using `console.log`?

Comment: _"I want to debug in a WebAssembly runtime environment"_ - https://developer.chrome.com/blog/wasm-debugging-2020/

Comment: If you want to test your code by producing console output, you probably don't need to run it in a browser. Running it in node.js from the command line will be easier.